# Resume next index in a for If a condition is true VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, for-loop

I want to resume the next index in a `for` if a condition is granted

The code i'm trying to use looks like this:

```
For i = 0 to 10
  If condition is true then
     Next i
  else
  'code
  end if
Next i
```

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
For i = 0 to 10
  If condition is False then
     'code
  end if
Next i
```

If the condition is True then you will just skip to the next `i` automatically

If the situation is more complicated, because of VBA's lack of a `Continue` construct, you would need to use a `GoTo`:

```
For i = 0 to 10
  'code
  If condition is true then
     'more code
     GoTo LoopBottom
  else
  'still more code
  end if
  'even more code
LoopBottom:
Next i
```

Comment: I can't believe I actually asked that, I'm kind of tired so that might be, but it was right and obvious hahaha thank you vm

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Not` in that if statement?

```
For i = 0 to 10
    If Not condition is true Then
        'code
    End If
Next i
```

Though John Coleman's answer is better if you wish to have a more complicated statement. His answer would also be more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it actually works with both answers !